Conservation of Angular Momentum in rotating arm
Consider an arm that can rotate along a central axis which is fixed at its left end. On the right end is a (homogeneous) disk that can rotate along its own central axis (disk axis) as shown in my sketch:

I want to understand how the angular velocities $\boldsymbol{\omega}_A$ and $\boldsymbol{\omega}_B$ are linked. The usual approach to this I have seen uses the law of conversation of angular momentum like so:
$$\boldsymbol{L}_A = \boldsymbol{L}_B \ \Leftrightarrow\ I_A \boldsymbol{\omega}_A = I_B \boldsymbol{\omega}_B \ \Leftrightarrow\ \boldsymbol{\omega}_A = \frac{I_B}{I_A} \boldsymbol{\omega}_B$$
where $I_A$ and $I_B$ are the moments of inertia of the whole arm and the disk itself. My questions are:

What changes (if any) when $\boldsymbol{r}$ is changed, e.g. $\boldsymbol{r}$ is doubled?
Is it okay to just set $\boldsymbol{L}_A$ equal to $\boldsymbol{L}_B$ as shown, even though they refer to diffrent axis?


Is $I_A$ just the moment of inertia of the disk referred to the central axis? Is it the arm+disk moment of inertia?
If just the disk, then $I_A = I_B + mr^2$ as per the parallel axis theorem, where $m$ is the disk mass. The theorem works even if angular momentum is not conserved.
Why does $\omega_B$ depend on $\omega_A$ though? Based on your information and schematic, it looks like the disk and the arm can be independently controlled.
Edit: Based on additional information provided by OP, if this is the bicycle wheel gyroscope scenario,
$$
I_A\omega_A = (I_B+mr^2)\omega_B
$$
referred to in the frame of reference attached to the pivot, aligned with the central axis of rotation.
Otherwise, $\omega_A$ and $\omega_B$ can be independently controlled.

$I_A$ is supposed to be the moment of inertia of the whole arm, so the disk and the piece connecting it to the central axis are conserned here. Also while $\boldsymbol{\omega}_A$ and $\boldsymbol{\omega}_B$ can be changed independently, the question is what happens to $\boldsymbol{\omega}_A$ if $\boldsymbol{\omega}_B$ changes. I think there should be a link as seen in this expirement: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/1/18/BehoudImpulsmoment.ogv/BehoudImpulsmoment.ogv.360p.webm

This isn't clear from your question. You are changing the axis of rotation of the disk after its spun, which due to conservation of angular momentum, causes the man to rotate as well. Please edit your question to include more details like these.

The link I provided is just an example. I do mean the situation described in the post. Sorry for the confusion

If you mean to say the situation described in the post is the moment after the wheel is turned, then you must conserve angular momentum in the z direction (along the central axis of rotation) as $I_A\omega_A$ = $(I_B+mr^2)\omega_B$

If this solved your doubts, please accept the answer. If not, we can look further into it
